# How to get the count of repeated values in PowerShell from an Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, powershell

PowerShell

[image]

Excel

[image]

I have added two attachments One is of PowerShell and other one is Excel  sheet.
I have coded to get the repeated values present in Excel Sheet. But this code functions only if they find exact values. But my Aim was to get the count of repetitive values present in every cell .
For example in my excel screenshot , If you Word "**Workday**" is present in **A2 and A6.** . I needed the count as 2 , but as per my PowerShell script its showing 1.

How to implement this feature?

Comment: Must you do this from Excel? If you save that as CSV file, things are so much easier..

Comment: ok could you please provide me the for this .. I mean for CSV File

Comment: Can you provide your own attempts at this using PowerShell? I too believe using a csv format would be easier to work with in this case.

Comment: Sure ..
Import-Csv Testing.csv |
Group-Object Name | 
Select-Object @{Name='Name'; Expression={$_.Values[0]}}, 
              @{Name='Message_Count'; Expression={$_.Count}}

I executed this , it shows the count too , but still its not upto the conditions I thought

Comment: @AbrahamZinala
As per the above table if I executed this code , I would only show the count of exact values..(please refer the table which is present in question)
for example in table above there are 2 "Jay" present  . but when I executed this code this is showing only 1 "jay" .
Count of "Jay" was 1 because  Jay present in  "Jay Mon" was not counted.
I want to count repetitive words present in every corner of cells

Comment: Update that into your question please.

Comment: Hello I have updated , can you please look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Abraham's solution, using `Group-Object` should get you close by using a scriptblock to define the custom property you would like to group by.  In this case we can check which names match other names and use one or the other (i chose to go with the shortest term)

```
# START TEST DATA
$data = @'
Name,PIA
Workday,23
Docusign,56
OneTrust,89
Mk Denial,78
How will you join Workday,45
Which Workday,23
OneTrust Maintenance,75
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
# END TEST DATA

# Replace $data below with Import-Csv Testing.csv
$data | Select-Object Name | Group-Object -Property {
    $item = $_
    if (($shortest = $data.name | Where-Object { $_ -ne $item.Name -and $item.name -match [regex]::Escape($_) } | Sort-Object {$_.Length} | Select-Object -First 1)) {
        $shortest
    }
    else {
        $item.Name
    }
} | Select-Object Count, Name, @{n = 'Items'; e = { $_.Group.Name -join ', ' } }
```

Output

```
Count Name      Items
----- ----      -----
    1 Docusign  Docusign
    1 Mk Denial Mk Denial
    2 OneTrust  OneTrust, OneTrust Maintenance
    3 Workday   Workday, How will you join Workday, Which Workday
```

### Update

To add the PIA column as comma-separated values like the Name column we can add another calculated property to `Select-Object`.  I added in a `Foreach-Object` loop in order to make the custom properties a bit more readable by first sorting the group by Name length first and then using this variable in both of the calculated properties

```
# Replace $data below with Import-Csv Testing.csv
$data | Group-Object -Property {
    $item = $_.Name
    $data.name | Where-Object { $item -match [regex]::Escape($_) } | Sort-Object { $_.Length } | Select-Object -First 1
} | ForEach-Object {
    $sortedGroup = $_.Group | Sort-Object { $_.Name.Length }
    $_ | Select-Object Count, Name, 
            @{n = 'Items'; e = { $sortedGroup.Name -join ', ' } }, 
            @{n = 'PIA';   e = { $sortedGroup.PIA -join ', ' } }
}
```

Output

```
Count Name      Items                                             PIA
----- ----      -----                                             ---
    1 Docusign  Docusign                                          56
    1 Mk Denial Mk Denial                                         78
    2 OneTrust  OneTrust, OneTrust Maintenance                    89, 75
    3 Workday   Workday, Which Workday, How will you join Workday 23, 23, 45
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I would like to add another identity near Items, ie PIA Number ..
I prefer this output, 
Count  Name         Items                                                  PIA
2          OneTrust   OneTrust, OneTrust Maintenance      89,75

Is it possible to modify this code ?,Could you please help me out? Also Can You share the best resources to learn PowerShell. I am new to this

Comment: You're welcome @LakshmanPillai.  Please see the update at the bottom of my answer for adding in the PIA data.  As for resources for learning PowerShell, honestly they are everywhere on the net.  Just search.  If you have LinkedIn Learn or Pluralsight, there are good courses to be found there.  StackOverflow, in my opinion, is also a great place to learn.  So many experienced and knowledgeable programmers and enthusiasts on this site to learn from.  Just stick around and soak it up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Daniel. I found a few courses related to PowerShell. There are a few modifications required. I will do that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Following from my comments, you were on the right path from what you responded with. [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-5.1) allows a *scriptblock* to be passed into your `-Property` parameter which you can in-turn use `-Replace` to replace the property with the name trying to be matched:

```
Import-Csv -Path ".\Testing.csv" | 
    Group-Object -Property { $_.Name -replace "(Jay)\w+",'$1' } -NoElement
```

Specifying `-NoElement` omits the members of the group from the results leaving you with:

```
Count Name                     
----- ----                     
    2 Ajay                     
    2 Jay                      
    1 Ray
```

Comment: Hello , can you please look into the question now. I have updated with more clarity , Could you please suggest where to add -NoElement in the code

Comment: @LakshmanPillai, okay just replace "Jay" with "OneTrust". `"(OneTrust)\w+"`

Comment: I don't want to specifically add , I need an automated process